# My Keras network with multi_gpu_model uses only 1 GPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras, multi-gpu

I have a problem when trying to use Keras with three GPUs.

My psuedocode is as follows:

```
import keras
import keras.models as M
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model 

i = M.Input(None,None,6) 
o1,o2,o3 = my_Network(i)

net = M.Model(inputs = i, outputs = [o1,o2,o3])
net = multi_gpu_model(net,gpus = 3) 

net.compile( ~~~~~ ) 
net.fit(~~~~~ )
```

My code is training my network, however, only one GPU is utilised.

My configuration is as follows:

> keras : 2.3.1
>
> tensorflow : 2.1.0
>
> Cuda : 10.0
>
> windows : 10
>
> GPU : Tesla 100 x 3 (VRAM : 32GB x 3 )

What is the mistake?

Comment: I'm not an expert on using multi gpu, but i check [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/10/30/how-to-multi-gpu-training-with-keras-python-and-deep-learning/) and seems you need to _build_ your model before do _multi_gpu_model(net,gpus = 3)_ using cpu.

Comment: Actually you just need to define your model once again using _with tf.device(......):_

Comment: Then Should I write the code like following ?  
'with tf.device('/gpu:0', '/gpu:1', '/gpu:2''):
     ~~~~~~~~~~'

Comment: No, use tf.device("/cpu:0") and then declare your model. Seems that you must to do that because cpu device combines information about all gpus computations and then join them. But to do this, cpu needs a "copy" of your model

Comment: Oh thanks for your advice. Then should I declare my model at  tf.device("/cpu:0"): using multi_gpu_model and also fit the model in  tf.device("/cpu:0")?

Comment: No, you just need to declare using cpu. Check the link in my first comment, there is an example there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that you must consider is the batch size when executing *fit*. You aren't showing this here but you need to make sure that you are giving it a batch size that is divisible by 3 in order to parallelize it across your 3 GPUs. If you are giving it a batch size of 1, for example, it will not be able to distribute the training across the GPUs.

You did not provide much information but based on your execution of *multi_gpu_model*, I don't see anything clearly wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I will make a try. I was using batch size = 64 , so maybe my computer could not understand it .

Comment: Have you tried this solution out? I'm just curious whether it has worked or not.

Comment: Unfortunately it still makes me use only 1 GPU.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by using codes under :

```
str = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/gpu:0","/gpu:1", "/gpu:2"])
with str.scope():
    epsnet = M.Model(inputs = [img_in,img_lv],outputs = [out_d,out_s,out_l])
    epsnet = multi_gpu_model(epsnet,gpus=3)
```

Hope this gives you some inspiration. 
Thank you all repliers.